# Apple Vision Kit - what foods can it detect?

Tags: swift, visionkit

Is there a list that I can look at? Is there a GitHub page or something? Any suggestions would be great.

I have looked everywhere and I have not been able to find anything.

Looked at apple documentation, reddit, and other places.

I greatly appreciate your help :)